# Load SharedPreferences in MainActivity and Update in an secondary activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

Good morning everyone,

I'm having problems again in my proccess to create my first app. This time with the SharedPreferences file.

I have 2 activities that must use the same SharedPreferences file. The first one is the MainActivity and the second one an edit layout for the data.

In the MainActivity I have the following method where I use the data to connect to a PLC:

```
        //initialize the SharedPreferences variables for the PLC Data and Connection
    m_DataPLC = getSharedPreferences("CFTPreferences",CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    m_DataEditorPLC = m_DataPLC.edit();

    //Gets the number from the IP Address for the connection with the PLC
    //As default, the system takes the value of a static string value
    //This is when the SharedPreferences file is empty
    m_IpAddress = getResources().getString(R.string.ip_Address);
    m_NewIpAddress = m_DataPLC.getString("newIpAddress", m_NewIpAddress);
    if(m_NewIpAddress == null)
    {
        m_DataEditorPLC.putString("newIpAddress", m_IpAddress.toString());
        m_DataEditorPLC.commit();
        m_OldIpAddress = m_NewIpAddress = m_IpAddress;
    }
    else
    {
        m_OldIpAddress = m_IpAddress = m_NewIpAddress; 
    }

    //Start the connection with the PLC
    m_Connection = new ModbusConnection(this,m_IpAddress);
    inet = m_Connection.loginPLC();
```

In my second activity, I have to load the same data and be able to modify it. What I do first is the login to the SharedPreferencesFile:

```
dataPLC = getSharedPreferences("CFTPreferences",CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
dataEditorPLC = dataPLC.edit();
```

Then I do the writing with a click action of a button:

```
    public void setIPAddress()
{
    if (!newIpAddress.equals(etIPAddress.getText().toString()))
    {
        dataEditorPLC.putString("oldIpAdd",ipAddress.toString());
        dataEditorPLC.putString("newIpAdd",etIPAddress.getText().toString());
        dataEditorPLC.commit();
    }
}
```

I dunno if I'm doing wrong calling the same file twice or if I have to do something extra to mend this. It looks like it does the update, but it doesn't refresh the MainActivity. If someone had some sort of the same problem, I would appreciate the help on this one!!!.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are accessing the value of Shared Preferences in `onCreate()` of first Activity. That will be your problem. Beacuse when you come back from second activity to first activity, your `onCreate()` is not called, instead `onResume()` is called. So the better thing to do is move the code where you access `SharedPreferences` value to a seperate function and call this function in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`.

for e.g.

```
public void getSharedPrefernces() {
  m_DataPLC = getSharedPreferences("CFTPreferences",CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
  m_NewIpAddress = m_DataPLC.getString("newIpAddress", m_NewIpAddress);
}
```

Hope this Helps..!! Cheers...

Comment: Dude is ok, not for a chick ;).

Yes, you're right, I changed it and did a new methode that it's called in all events (Start, Create, Resume, Pause and Restart). I also found an error in the secondary activity which was related with the edit text inside of the code. I solved my problem I think with this. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ha..ha.. I did not look at your name or anything before answering. just put it randomly.. Sorry lady...:)